# How to add class to element only if it already does not have it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

How to add a class to an element only if it already does not have it? Say we don't know if the element has `class="desired_class ...` but we want to make sure it has.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this

```
var elem = $('selector');
if(!elem.hasClass('desired_class')){
  elem.addClass('desired_class');
 }
```

Comment: This requires jQuery.

Answer (score 93):

Also, you can use `classList` property and it's `add()` method:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myElement');
element.classList.add('myClass');
```

The class name will be added only if the element does not have it.

More about `classList`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Easily the best answer. No idea why there isn't more upvotes.

Comment: Sadly not in IE 9, if that matters to you. Source: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_domtokenlist_add

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a JavaScript-only function that checks if the class exists before adding it to the element. (You can always use `classList` as mentioned here, but support for that starts with IE10.)

```js
function addClass(name, element) {
  var classesString;
  classesString = element.className || "";
  if (classesString.indexOf(name) === -1) {
    element.className += " " + name;
  }
}

var element = document.getElementById('some-element');

addClass("on", element); // Adds the class 'on'
addClass("on", element); // Ignored
addClass("on", element); // Ignored

document.write('Element classes: ' + element.className);
```

```html
<div id="some-element"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In plain javascript check class existence by using below code. Here I'm checking el (element) has tempClass or not

```
var el = document.getElementById("div1");

...

if (el.classList.contains("tempClass")){
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('element').hasClass('some_class')) {
   $('element').addClass('class_name');
}
```

Comment: this wont work because $(this) will not reference to $('element')

Comment: why not just `$('element').addClass('class_name');` jquery will check the existence of the class for you

Comment: This requires jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to do it with JQuery only? You can do it with simple JavaScript

```
    document.getElementById("elementId").getAttribute("class")
```

will give you null if the class attribute is not present.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. What if the element has a class, but not the one you're interested in adding?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$("your_element").hasClass("desired_class")) {
  $("your_element").addClass("desired_class");
}
```

Comment: this wont work because $(this) will not reference to $(your-element)

Comment: This requires jQuery.

Answer (score -4):

An updated answer to this question is using `toggleClass`

```
 $( "element" ).toggleClass( "className" );
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Your code will actually remove class if it exists already. It will toggle it.